# Why doesn't stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown, true) work?

Tags: actionscript-3, events, keyboard

I want to listen to stage for keyboard event, and I want to catch an event directly when it appears (not in bubbling or target). Why can't I do this?

Actually it seems that I can't use `useCapture` for keyboard events at all.

I want to open my inner console window by pressing tilda button, and change focus to input field. So, I wrote something like this

```
    public function init(stage:Stage):void
    {
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onStageKeyDown);
    }

    private function onStageKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void
    {
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();

        switch(event.keyCode)
        {
            case Keyboard.BACKQUOTE:
                visible = !visible;
                stage.focus = visible ? inputField : stage;
                break;
        }
    }
```

The problem is, it writes "`" character in my input, which I don't want it to do. So, I decided to try to listen to keyboard event in capture phase to stop its propagation. But it seems that stage can't have capture phase, because there is no nodes before it. How can I handle that situation properly?

Comment: You can use keydown on the capture phase.  Perhaps if you explained your current application and showed the relevant source code someone will actually help you...

Comment: update post with additional information

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally found a workaround for this problem.

First of all: handling and stopping `KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN` is NOT preventing `TextField` from getting input. That's sad because in this case it would be useful, but it seems there is some other reasons for not doing this.

So, what I should do is listen for `TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT` by `inputField`

```
        inputField.addEventListener(TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT, onTextInput);
```

and listen to `KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN` by `stage`

```
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onStageKeyDown);
```

in case I may still want to put `tilda` of `backquote` signs in my `TextField` (for example by coping and pasting them) I decided to use a flag

```
    private function onStageKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void
    {
        switch(event.keyCode)
        {
            case Keyboard.BACKQUOTE:

                ...
                inAction = true;
                break;
        }
    }
```

so when `TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT`event fires I can see if that was opening window action or not. And if it is, then `preventDefault()` behaviour, which means NOT inputting received sign in `TextField`

```
    private function onTextInput(event:TextEvent):void
    {
        if(inAction)
        {
            event.preventDefault();
            inAction = false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To simply answer your question, you can listen for keyboard events on the capture phase.

Most likely, the reason you can't, is because nothing has focus. If nothing has focus in your application then the stage will not get a keyboard event.  By default, when a swf runs nothing has focus.

Give an item focus when your application starts (anything besides the stage itself), and the event will come.

```
public function init(stage:Stage):void
{
    stage.focus = this; //assuming this is the document class
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onStageKeyDown, true);
}
```

---

Now, to follow up with what you are actually trying to accomplish (aside from your actual question) all you need to do is listen for the right event (TEXT_INPUT).   Your answer is close, but it can be much simpler without the need for flags or a key down listener:

```
stage.focus = this; //give something focus, probably not needed if you have to click the text input in order to input text

//listen on the capture phase for text input
stage.addEventListener(TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT, onStageTextInput, true);

function onStageTextInput(event:TextEvent):void
{
    switch(event.text)
    {
        //if the new text was a backquote or @ sign, don't let the event trigger it's normal action
        case "`":
        case "@":
            event.preventDefault(); //prevent default is needed
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as I know clicking around a window changes stage's focus, so that means there is always opportunity for needed object to lose focus.

Comment: @user1496491 - yes (if what you are clicking is interactive), but so long as it's a child of the stage that has focus it won't be an issue.   This is the strict answer to your question.